# Protocol conformance of system classes using more generic types

Tags: swift

To mock objects in Swift for test, I generally follow a pattern of authoring a Protocol describing the behaviour of the object I'd like, and then using Cuckoo to generate mocks for it for test.

Usually, these protocols map directly onto existing types, and this works fine, until I need to make the existing type work with my new protocol types.

```
public typealias RequestCompletionHandler = (Request, Error?) -> Swift.Void

public protocol Request {
  var results: [Any]? { get }
  var completionHandler: RequestCompletionHandler? { get }
}

extension VNRequest: Request {}
```

Here, `VNRequest` already has a member called `completionHandler` that returns the following type:

`public typealias VNRequestCompletionHandler = (VNRequest, Error?) -> Swift.Void`

Technically, all of these types should match up, but obviously it's not a very easy scenario for the type solver to solve, so the compiler isn't too cheerful about it.

At first I thought I'd be able to refer to the original completionBlock implementation by doing the following:

```
extension VNRequest: Request {
  public var completionHandler: RequestCompletionHandler? {
    return (self as VNRequest).completionHandler
  }
}
```

But it's not too happy about that either.

Any advice about how best to do this? I've thought about using a different name in the protocol (e.g: `completionBlock_` or `completionBlock$`), which works, but it's a bit scrappy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs due to the fact that Swift is covariant in respect to closure return type, and contra-variant in respect to its arguments. Which means that `(VNRequest, Error?) -> Void` can't be used where `(Request, Error?) -> Void` is needed (the other way around is possible).

You can solve your problem by using an associated type in the `Request` protocol:

```
public protocol Request {
    associatedtype RequestType = Self
    var results: [Any]? { get }
    var completionHandler: ((RequestType, Error?) -> Void)? { get }
}
```

The above protocol definition will make the `VNRequest` class compile, as the compiler will detect the match for `RequestType`.

The downside, though, is that protocols with associated types have some limitations regarding where they can be used, and also passing them as function arguments will require some `where` clauses to make them work.

---

Another alternative would be to use `Self` as a parameter to the completion handler:

```
public typealias RequestCompletionHandler<T> = (T, Error?) -> Swift.Void

public protocol Request {
    var results: [Any]? { get }
    var completionHandler: RequestCompletionHandler<Self>? { get }
}
```

This will also solve the conformance issue, but also comes with some constraints: `VNRequest` must be final, the functions using `Request` must be generic:

```
func send<R: Request>(_ request: R)
```

Comment: That does work, but unfortunately the noise added via `where` clauses is almost worse than simply suffixing the var/function names.

Comment: @G.Ear yeah, that's one of the downsides.

Comment: @G.Ear found another solution, check the updated answer.